# How to display RSS date & author name from parser xml in iOS

Tags: ios, xml, rss

I have an iOS app that reads an RSS feed from my Wordpress site. The app shows the post title and also caches the thumbnail image. I also want to display the date and author name in the RSS feed table in my iOS app.. how can I do that?

Here is how the app caches the post title:

```
postTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
postTitle.numberOfLines = 3;
postTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
postTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
postTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
postTitle.frame = CGRectMake(30, 20, 200, 65 );

cell.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

postTitle.text = [[self.parseResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:postTitle];`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement custom subclass `UITableViewCell` and include two additional property `rssDate` and `authorName` to it.

If you are already using `UITableViewCell` custom subclass then consider adding these two properties (perhaps, as a `UILabel`)

**EDIT**

For getting `RSSDate` and `AuthorName` see for their tags in `XML` and parse the same way as you have parsed `Title` for the feed. No one can tell you, how to parse these both without seeing your XML Structure.

Comment: Yes I already use UItableView Cell ,but how it will get the author name and rss feed date ? I think this is not complete ..

Comment: Yes this is correct the date is showing now .. I will try for author name and if I get it I will vote for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, but I want to change the date format, it's showing like this : Tue 02 Apr, 2013 , 09:19:59 +0000, .. so how can I edit this? in the parser i used element@"Pupdate"; I need to edit this date format & put label @"Date" behind this date .. how I can do that ?

Comment: You may consider searching over this site; you will definitely get the answer; If not, consider posting another question for that.

Comment: Ok thanks I will post another question for that, & I will vote your answer :)